# get element by name, when name is an empty string

Tags: r

How does one extract elements from a vector (by name), if the name is an empty string (e.g. "")?

```
a <- c(15,25)
names(a) <- c("", "second")
a[names(a)[2]]
#second 
#    25 
#a[names(a)[1]]
#<NA> 
#  NA 
a
#       second 
#    15     25
```

Thanks!

Edit: Thanks for the suggestions, but they don't allow for the flexibility I need. I should clarify my intended goal. Let's say I have a vector as such:

```
fvec <- c("hi", "hi", "hi", "", "")
# ["hi", "hi", "hi", "", ""]
```

Now I'd like to tabulate this vector, and then replace the instances with a new string that includes the sample count.

```
# ["hi (n=3)", "hi (n=3)", "hi (n=3)", " (n=2)", " (n=2)"]
```

I'd been using:

```
tab <- table(fvec)
# fvec
#    hi 
#  2  3 
retval <- sprintf("%s (n=%d)", fvec, tab[fvec])
# "hi (n=3)" "hi (n=3)" "hi (n=3)" " (n=NA)"  " (n=NA)"
```

Comment: How about `a[!nzchar(names(a))]`

Comment: From `?names`: The name ‘""’ is special: it is used to indicate that there is no name associated with an element of a (atomic or generic) vector.
Subscripting by ‘""’ will match nothing (not even elements which have no name).

Comment: Argh, that's annoying. I guess I should recode blanks as NAs in my data. @nicola, if you want to add that as an answer I will accept and add a comment with my workaround.

Comment: @fanli - No you shouldn't.  If you rename the `""` to `NA` you'll just get NA vector values when you try to use it.  `names(a)[1] <- NA; a[NA]`

Comment: I just posted an extract from the doc, so guess no answer is needed. However, in your case is better to use `match` as @akrun mentioned in his answer.

Comment: So here's the workaround I'm using now. Thanks to @akrun for the `match` idea. `retval <- sprintf("%s (n=%d)", fvec, tab[unlist(lapply(fvec, function(x) match(x, names(tab))))])` @RichScriven, what would you recommend coding missing values as? Is it safe to use "NA" as a string?

Answer (score 2):

We can use a logical index to extract the element

```
a[names(a)==""]

#15
```

Or with `match`

```
a[match("", names(a))]
```

---

Regarding the OP's output for `sprintf`, we can get the expected output with `match`

```
sprintf("%s (n=%d)", fvec, tab[match(fvec, names(tab))])
#[1] "hi (n=3)" "hi (n=3)" "hi (n=3)" " (n=2)"   " (n=2)"
```

Comment: Yes, however I want to avoid hard coding for an empty string. The best I've come up with so far uses `apply` in a stupid way..

Comment: @fanli  If you have an empty string as name, you can rename it with `make.names` i.e. `names(a) <- make.names(names(a)); a[names(a)[1]]`